# How can i move a point through both x-axis and y-axis while the curve is not changed in a chart.js line graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have an equation of y=x^2 to draw a curve graph, i am using chart.js and i have already drawn the curve and i have a slider where the user inputs the x value.

When the user slide the slider an x value is generated enter the equation and the y value is generated

what i want is while the curve is drawn without being changed i create a new dot with the new point (x,y) and put it on the curve and whenever the user changes the x value this point move over the curve to go to it's right position

Comment: could you post the code you have so far. it will be easier to add to it vs building it from scratch. cheers!

Comment: `point.x = x;` `point.y= x^2;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slide event move your point from the existing position to the new position.

Assuming you have Chart.js, jQuery and jQuery-UI

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**Script**

```
// y = fn(x)
function myFunction(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
}

// construct data
var labels = [];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10;) {
    labels.push(i);
    data.push(myFunction(i));
    i += 0.25;
}


// move point to position x in myChart
function updateChartPoint(myChart, xValue) {
    var ctx = myChart.chart.ctx;
    var scale = myChart.scale;
    var scaling = (scale.width - (scale.xScalePaddingLeft + scale.xScalePaddingRight)) / (scale.xLabels[scale.xLabels.length - 1] - scale.xLabels[0]);

    // cancel existing animations
    if (myChart.animationLoop)
        clearInterval(myChart.animationLoop);

    // figure out where we want to go
    var xTarget = Math.round(scale.xScalePaddingLeft + xValue * scaling);
    var xCurrent;
    if (myChart.point)
        xCurrent = myChart.point.x;
    else
        xCurrent = xTarget;
    var increment = (xTarget - xCurrent) / 30;

    myChart.animationLoop = setInterval(function () {
        myChart.point = {
            x: xCurrent,
            y: scale.calculateY(myFunction((xCurrent - scale.xScalePaddingLeft) / scaling))
        }

        myChart.update();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(myChart.point.x, myChart.point.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();

        // move / stop moving
        if (Math.abs(xTarget - xCurrent) <= Math.abs(increment))
            clearInterval(myChart.animationLoop);
        else
            xCurrent += increment;
    }, 5);
}


$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.1,
    value: 5
});


var data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: data
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    showTooltips: false,
    pointDot: false,
    // the initial setting of the point
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        if (!this.point) {
            var chart = this;
            chart.options.animation = false;

            $('#slider').slider("option", "slide", function (event, ui) {
                updateChartPoint(chart, ui.value)
            })

            updateChartPoint(chart, $('#slider').slider("option", "value"))
        }
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tjvz8c5o/

Comment: how can i target the red circle in the canvas which is the moving point to add an event hover to show a tooltip ? @potatopeelings

Comment: I think that should be easy enough with the chartjs code. Mind posting it as a separate question? I'll take a shot at it in a couple of hours - meanwhile you could get other folks chipping in too. Cheers!

Comment: [ask] when i have changed the equation the point didn't move on the arc exactly , what should i do ?

Comment: You can just plug your equation into the fiddle above and we can take a look. Or you do the same thing and post it as a separate question (be sure to include the code as well in the question in addition to the fiddle) too because your new question is now why doesn't this work when you have a different equation. What is your equation btw? Cheers!

Comment: my new equation is  Y = log( x / (x- 1000 * (4/100) / 12))  / log(1+ (4/100) / 12) ; .. but i solved the problem anyway ..

Comment: Awesome! You still need the tooltip, yes?